# Communicate with Python or Java from native iOS Objective-C app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, rally

Is there any way to use Python/Java code alongside Objective-C/XCode/etc? (e.g., Write my app in Objective-C and then access function calls in Python/Java?)

I want to be able to communicate with Rally via an iPhone app, but, as I understand it, Rally APIs are in Python and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Rally's Java and Python toolkits are just wrappers around Rally's REST webservices API. Your best bet is to leverage an Objective C Rest Toolkit such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) to build your app to interface with Rally's REST services directly.